# The current user has insufficient permissions to perform this operation. Add Termset in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to bind a field to a termset, and if the termset does not exist I want to create it by code. However, even when the code is running with elevated privileges I get the following exception.

The current user has insufficient permissions to perform this operation.

```
public static void BindTaxonomyField(string taxonomyFieldId, string taxonomyNoteFieldId, string termSetName, string termGroup, SPWeb web)
        {
            try
            {
                if (web != null)
                {
                    // get the taxonomyfield from the sitecollection
                    var field = web.Fields[new Guid(taxonomyFieldId)] as TaxonomyField;
                    if (field != null)
                    {
                        // attach the note field
                        field.TextField = new Guid(taxonomyNoteFieldId);

                        // set up the field for my termstore
                        var session = new TaxonomySession(web.Site);

                        if (session.TermStores.Count > 0)
                        {
                            // get termstore values
                            TermStore ts = session.TermStores[0];
                            Group group = GetGroup(termGroup, ts);
                            if (group == null)
                            {
                                ts.CreateGroup(termGroup);
                                //throw new Exception("Group was not found in the termstore");
                            }

// ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
                            TermSet termSet = group.TermSets.Any(s => s.Name == termSetName) ? group.TermSets[termSetName] : group.CreateTermSet(termSetName);
// ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException

                            //TermSet termSet = group.TermSets[termSetName];

                            // actually setup the field for using the TermStore
                            field.SspId = ts.Id;
                            field.TermSetId = termSet.Id;
                        }

                        field.Update();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }


 private void BindColumnsToTermStore(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                {
                    using (var site = new SPSite(url))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            if (!web.AllowUnsafeUpdates)
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;



                            BindTaxonomyField("EF810CD2-F2D2-4BD2-9ABF-C19815F13568",
                                                                           "67E6E777-0D1E-4840-B858-17400CFABD14",
                                                                           "Business Audience", "IctDocumentation",
                                                                           web);


                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go in to central administration and navigate to your term store(this is in the left hand nav) in the main container of the page there is a box with a few usernames. Is the account you are running the code in listed? If not stick them in there.

i think the path is something like Central admin -> Manage service application -> Managed meta data service - and the are on the page is call Term store Administrators

There is also one more place you must check but check this first and them run again.

The next place to check is to highlight your Manage metadata service which is located 
Central admin -> Manage service application
and click on permissions on the ribbon and make sure the users your running the code with has the correct access.

I always start by making sure i know who i am running the code as first of all then do the checks

Comment: but I am running with elevated privileges, that is supposed to run as SYSTEM

Comment: I understand that you are running with elevated privileges however this ( I believe) makes your code run in the context of the application pool account but all dependant of where your calling the code from. Go to the pages above and check to see if the account you think your running in the context of is granted permissions. If it isn't then that may be the cause of your problem if not I suggest you find out exactly what account your running in. I have many a time thought I was running in the correct account and found out I haven't been.

Comment: Add the application pool account as term store administrator and you'll be fine running with elevated privileges